# Como se puede hacer para que la barra de busquedas del admin de django busque sin presionar enter?

Tags: django, django-admin, busqueda

El problema: Tengo la barra de busqueda del admin de django, funciona, el problema es que cada vez que borro la busqueda debo volver a enviar la peticion apretando en "busca" para que me vuelva a mostrar todo. Me gustaria que sea como una barra de busqueda normal, si la borras te muestre todos los registros y cuando vas escribiendo vaya filtrando.

class Alumnos (admin.ModelAdmin):

```
list_display = ('id_alumno', 'email_registro_alumno', 'alumno_habilitado')
search_fields = ('id_alumno', 'email_registro_alumno','alumno_habilitado')
```

Saludos

Comment: A la pregutna le falta información. No muestras el codigo que has probado para conseguir lo que buscas. No muestras el clickHandler de tu botón buscar. .. etc Mejora la pregunta para no recibir puntuaciones negativas y que te la cierren.

Answer (score 0):

Django admin no admite esto por defecto. Te va a tocar picartelo,

puedes usar la típica fuinción en Js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  const searchField = $('input[name="q"]');
  searchField.on('input', function() {
    $(this).parents('form').submit();
  });
});
```

Es posible sobrescribir el template de administración de Django para incluir un template propio, por ejemplo: admin_custom_js.html, que cargue ese Js:

```
{% load static %}
<script src="{% static 'js/admin_search.js' %}"></script>
```

Esto lo haces (dependiendo de la versión de django, claro, creando un archivo base_site.html en la carpeta templates/admin de tu aplicación para sobreescribir el orginal. Y entonces añades tu template como parte del mismo:

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}    ---->   extiendes el template original de admin

{% block extra_js %}   ----> añades tu template con el código js que permite esas llamadas
  {% include "admin_custom_js.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Hola, te sugerimos revisar: [CHATGPT está prohibido](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5462/pol%c3%adtica-temporal-chatgpt-est%c3%a1-prohibido), saludos.